# MongoDB Driver in .NET System.InvalidOperationException: '{document}{date}.Year is not supported.'

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to get a List of all UserData by a specific User in one Day.

```
public async Task<List<UserData>> GetAllUserDataByDataAsync(string UserId, DateTime date) =>
        await _userDataCollection.Find(x => x.UserId == UserId
                                       && x.Timestamp.Year == date.Year
                                       && x.Timestamp.Month == date.Month
                                       && x.Timestamp.Day == date.Day).ToListAsync();
```

But I get the following error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: '{document}{date}.Year is not
> supported.

How do I fix this?

Comment: see `Unsupported builder..`  section here https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/frequently_encountered_issues/

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your expression so that it does not perform the .Year/Month/Day operations on the Mongo timestamp, like this:

```
&& x.Timestamp >= date && x.Timestamp < date.AddDays(1)
```